# How to check trend and seasonal component plots?

Tags: statistics, time-series, analytics, forecasting, timeserieschart

I am given a month worth of data and I need to inspect the stationary properties of the series by checking on their trend and seasonal component plots. May I know how do I do so?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose function is used for that. For Python you could use [this](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html).